# Angular 4, XHR Failed loading: POST

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api2

I've followed this article to develop a token based authenticated back-end service:

http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/

This all works as expected and I can authenticate using a winforms app no problems with retrieving the token using restsharp in c#.  Now I've come to develop a web front end using Angular 4 and am trying to modify this:

http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/08/16/angular-2-jwt-authentication-example-tutorial

to get the token from my back end using this code:

```html
 login(username: string, password: string): Observable<boolean> {

        let data = "grant_type=password&username=" + username + "&password=" + password;

        let headers  = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });
        //headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');

        let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});

        return this.http.post('http://localhost:61814/token', data, options)
        .map((response: Response) => {
            // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
            let user = response.json();
            if (user && user.token) {
                // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
            }
        
            return user;
        })
        
    }
```

```html
login() {
        this.loading = true;
        this.authenticationService.login(this.model.username, this.model.password)
            .subscribe(
                data => {
                    this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
                },
                error => {
                    this.alertService.error(error);
                    this.loading = false;
                });
    }
```

but nothing happens when I debug in chrome devtools, nothing in network tab and only a XHR failed loading: POST" in the console.

Pretty new to front end development and really struggling with this!

Comment: It looks fine to me. If you put console.log in the various methods, are they all getting called?

Comment: Yes, they are now.  I restarted my back-end solution and it seems to work.  Struggle over!  thanks

Answer (score 1):

If your **Backend Project** is a seperate project and api project that runs in **http:\localhost:61814** and your **Frontend Project** is an angular project that runs in **http:\localhost:4200**, Your problem is Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) for this problem you must make **proxy.config.json** inside angular project and put inside this codes:

```
{
    "/api/*": {
        "target": "http://localhost:61814",
        "secure": false,
        "logLevel": "debug"
    }
}
```

and then for affecting this file into angular project for running anular project use

> npm start (instead of ng serve)

Answer (score 1):

If your backend API project run on the **http:\localhost:61814** then you need set CROS(Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) filter if you send token in header with key **Authorization**

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with, authorization, cache-control");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Authorization");
```

And in login(username: string, password: string) service function should ...

```
enter code herelogin(username: string, password: string): Observable<boolean> {

    let data = "grant_type=password&username=" + username + "&password=" + password;

    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});

    return this.http.post('http://localhost:61814/token', data, options)
     .map((response: Response) => {
            // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
            return response;
        });

}
```

And login() function

```
login() {
    this.loading = true;
    this.authenticationService.login(this.model.username, this.model.password)
        .subscribe(
            data => {
            let token = data.headers.get('Authorization')
            //console.log(this.token)
            // store username and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
            sessionStorage.setItem('token', token);

                this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
            },
            error => {
                this.alertService.error(error);
                this.loading = false;
            });
}
```

Comment: if any problem then tell me I will help you.